# SQL SELECT query takes too long after updating the version

Tags: mysql, optimization

To begin with, here is my query:

```
SELECT 
  pd.meterclass, pd.meterscore, pd.rt_url, pd.imdbId, pd.title, pd.adult,
  pd.backdrop,pd.budget, pd.homepage, pd.plot, pd.poster, pd.release_date,
  pd.revenue, pd.runtime, pd.language, pd.tagline, pd.status, 
  pd.imdbRatings, pd.imdbVotes, mg.genre_id, cst.cast_id,  
  cst.character_name, cst.name, 
  cst.profile_path, crw.job, crw.name as crew_name, 
  crw`enter code here`.profile_path as crew_profile_path, crw.id as crew_id, 
  crw.credit_id as crew_credit_id 
FROM (
       SELECT * 
       from movie_data_primary  
       WHERE cinestopId="8QRJTD"
     ) pd 
INNER JOIN movie_genre mg ON pd.cinestopId = mg.cinestopId 
INNER JOIN movie_cast cst ON cst.cinestopId  = pd.cinestopId 
INNER JOIN movie_crew crw ON crw.cinestopId = cst.cinestopId;
```

Before I upgrade my MySQL version to 5.7, this query used to take around 3 seconds (not the most optimal time, but tolerable anyway). After the upgrade, it takes more than half an hour. Here's the profile:

```
+----------------------+------------+
| Status               | Duration   |
+----------------------+------------+
| starting             |   0.000221 |
| checking permissions |   0.000013 |
| checking permissions |   0.000006 |
| checking permissions |   0.000004 |
| checking permissions |   0.000008 |
| Opening tables       |   0.000039 |
| init                 |   0.000158 |
| System lock          |   0.000018 |
| optimizing           |   0.000025 |
| statistics           |   0.002507 |
| preparing            |   0.000063 |
| executing            |   0.000007 |
| Sending data         | 999.999999 |
| end                  |   0.000013 |
| query end            |   0.000012 |
| closing tables       |   0.000012 |
| freeing items        |   0.002281 |
| cleaning up          |   0.000023 |
+----------------------+------------+
```

The field 'cinestopId' is indexed. Can someone tell me what's going berserk?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you break the query and create table from create temporary table t1 as select * from movie_data_primary  WHERE cinestopId="8QRJTD"; and then use this table in join instead..

Comment: Actually, I have done that in the query.

Comment: Did you read the notes on how the optimizer may have changed? Was the service restarted? I'm thinking the plan used to be in cache but now it has to be read from disk back into memory? What did the query plan before and after look like? Are the wait types the same before and after?

Comment: @Shaulinator can you please explain a bit more? I am very new to SQL. Yes indeed, the service was restarted after the upgrade.

Comment: Do you have a backup of the database before you upgraded? What was the version you upgraded from? Can you post the query plan? This site will tell you about the query plan. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html When you restart the service, anything that was in memory gets dumped. As you run queries, the service caches them in memory so it can be re-used again and be much faster. MySQL also optimizes how best to execute your query, it stashes these ideas on how to best do this in memory. If it leaves memory, it must go back to disk for that information.

Comment: Yes, I have a backup. But I guess if I query for some cinestopId that hasn't been queried before, that would've to be fetched from the disk? I upgraded from 5.5, and even new queries did not take more than 3 seconds then.

Comment: @Shaulinator I'll post the query plan once I have my hands on my machine. Travelling currently. Thanks.

Comment: (1) Yes there were a lot of changes in 5.7.  But this does not seem like a likely one to have been broken.  (2) Can you provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both versions?  They may give some clues.  (3) `999.999999` is a suspicious number.  (4) Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`  (I'm concerned about datatypes, etc.)  (5) Did `innodb_buffer_file_size` change?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the query without joining against a subselect?

```
SELECT 
  pd.meterclass, pd.meterscore, pd.rt_url, pd.imdbId, pd.title, pd.adult,
  pd.backdrop,pd.budget, pd.homepage, pd.plot, pd.poster, pd.release_date,
  pd.revenue, pd.runtime, pd.language, pd.tagline, pd.status, 
  pd.imdbRatings, pd.imdbVotes, mg.genre_id, cst.cast_id,  
  cst.character_name, cst.name, 
  cst.profile_path, crw.job, crw.name as crew_name, 
  crw`enter code here`.profile_path as crew_profile_path, crw.id as crew_id, 
  crw.credit_id as crew_credit_id 
FROM movie_data_primary pd
INNER JOIN movie_genre mg ON pd.cinestopId = mg.cinestopId 
INNER JOIN movie_cast cst ON cst.cinestopId  = pd.cinestopId 
INNER JOIN movie_crew crw ON crw.cinestopId = cst.cinestopId;
WHERE pd.cinestopId="8QRJTD"
```